# Could not find goal '' in plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.1.4.RELEASE among available goals repackage

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I ran a spring application in eclipse yesterday (I have Windows 7). I ran it today through the command prompt using the command: `mvn spring-boot: run`

This time it didn't work and I got the message:

```
Could not find goal '' in plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.1.4.RELEASE among available goals repackage
```

Since I have not changed the code I don't know why it doesn't work and what I should I do to run it again. I have also tried an older project which doesn't run either and which gets the same error message.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

change

```
mvn spring-boot: run
```

to

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

**note**: remove space after `:`