# could not find goal in plugin

Tags: maven, tomcat, java-web-start

I see the following error message:

```
Could not find goal '' in plugin org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2 
among available goals exec-war-only, deploy-only, redeploy-only, help, shutdown, 
                      run-war-only, standalone-war-only, run, deploy, standalone-war, 
                      undeploy, run-war, redeploy, exec-war
```

I can't find the error position, so how can I avoid this error?

Comment: it is the first for me to use the tool,because of my carelessness，so generating this error. so the jsp file should be in place,that is my suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

As illustrated [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24720016/6309), it depends on the exact mvn command you are executing.

Regarding the [`tomcat7-maven-plugin`](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/), and [its goals](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html), you need to execure for instance

```
mvn tomcat7:deploy
```

Not `tomcat7: deploy`: the extra space would trigger the error message `Could not find goal '' in plugin ...`